# Failed to retrieve data from database

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I'm trying to use Crystal Reports and I connect it to a stored procedure which takes two parameters.

The user fills two text boxes and I'm trying to pass these parameters to my stored procedure.

But I get this error

> failed to retrieve data from database

Here is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Check(txtFrmDt, txtTDt))
        {
            CryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            CrtableLogonInfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            CrtableLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            CrConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

            CryRpt.Load("E:\\Users\\Mostafa\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\Sales and Inventory System\\Sales and Inventory System\\Inventory_Report.rpt");

            ParameterFields = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterFields();
            ParameterField = new ParameterField();
            ParameterValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            ParameterField.Name = "@Param1";
            ParameterValue.Value = txtFrmDt.Text;
            ParameterField.CurrentValues.Add(ParameterValue);
            ParameterFields.Add(ParameterField);
            CryRpt.SetParameterValue("@Param1", ParameterValue);

            ParameterField.Name = "@Param2";
            ParameterValue.Value = txtTDt.Text;
            ParameterField.CurrentValues.Add(ParameterValue);
            ParameterFields.Add(ParameterField);
            CryRpt.SetParameterValue("@Param2", ParameterValue);

            CrConnectionInfo.ServerName = "mostafa-pc";
            CrConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "sales and inventory system";
            CrConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
            CrConnectionInfo.Password = "1";

            CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                CrtableLogonInfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                CrtableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = CrConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(CrtableLogonInfo);
            }

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
        }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try to update database for any changes?

Comment: @Faisal   i didn't change the data base is this needed?!

Comment: It is needed if stored procedure is changed

Comment: @Faisal well it didn't change at all

Comment: Did you try to check the preview of the report by sending same values in crystal reports?

Comment: @Faisal how should I do that?

Comment: Open report and click on second tab below report